# Trying to calculate the Average of the non zero rows in a column in an RDLC

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, reportviewer2008

Is there any way to caculate the average of the non zero rows only for a column of data in a table in an RDLC for Microsoft report viewer?

ie
0
0
0
5
5
= 5 not 2

I tried Count( fields.n.value > 0 ) to get the count of non zero rows, but it returned the 
count of all rows.

Thanks!

Eric-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Sum(Fields!n.Value > 0) / Sum(IIf(Fields!n.Value > 0, 1, 0))
```

Notice how the average is computed manually by summing all values then dividing by another sum that mimics a specialized count mechanism.

Comment: For anyone who follows, you actually need to do this to handle the case that there are zero non zero columns ) IN this case I'm doing money.... =FormatCurrency( iif( Sum( IIf(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value > 0, 1, 0) ) , Sum(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value > 0) / Sum(IIf(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value > 0, 1, 0)), 0 ) )

Comment: Corrected for minor typo.

=FormatCurrency( iif( Sum( IIf(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value > 0, 1, 0) ) , Sum(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value ) / Sum(IIf(Fields!SixMonEarn.Value > 0, 1, 0)), 0 ) )